# (base) (null) in Mac Terminal Window

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I have recently started a course in Computer Vision with Python and I was trying to install the OpenCV libraries, this resulted in no luck at all and I can't run any of the code. I tried re-installing, then using some advice on other stackoverflow queries and it's resulted in this:

```
(base) (null):~ DewiMadden$
```

I'm a rookie to all this as I have only previously used MATLAB and that often didn't require me to step out in to the terminal windows.

Help would be appreciated.

Dewi

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use conda environments. Have you tried installing opencv in your base environment with the Anaconda navigator? It might be easier to do it that way if you're not comfortable yet with using a terminal. Do you know which version of python and which version of opencv you need to be able to run the code you speak of?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If I am honest, I am a bit lost. I know I am using Python 3 but not sure which OpenCV version. I installed it using the pip install opencv-contrib command. 

Let me have a quick look. Is the Anaconda navigator within the app?

Comment: It's Python 3 with OpenCV 3.4.2.

Comment: By the way, have you tried running "import cv2" with python to check if opencv is already installed?

Comment: Anaconda Navigator is a desktop application that you can use to manage conda python environments. You can use it to install packages without using the terminal.

Comment: It says
```
(null):finding-lanes DewiMadden$ import cv2
bash: import: command not found
```

Even though Anaconda says the package is installed.

Comment: You should start up python first, before typing "import cv2", otherwise, your terminal thinks it should look for a terminal command called "import". So:

Comment: first do $python then within python try "import cv2"

Comment: It just says no module named cv2. I just checked again and it says I have Python 2.7 even though I thought it was 3. Is this a problem?

Comment: It is only a problem if you need python 3 to run the code you want to run. Have you tried to run $conda install -c menpo opencv in your terminal?

Comment: If you can't figure it out, I would really recommend installing anaconda navigator. https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/

Comment: Yes I have done that. I have managed to get python to recognise the cv2 import now thankfully. Need to reinstall PyCharm now to update to Python 3.